# FFTW c2c Fourier space symmetry in 3-D in Fortran

Tags: fortran, fft, fftw

I am running into difficulty using the FFTW c2c inverse Fourier transform and I suspect it has to do with properly defining the complex conjugate portion of the 3-D complex array. I am generating a representation of turbulent velocity fluctuations in Fourier space on a 3-D periodic domain, applying what I believe to be the correct complex conjugate terms and then calling the FFTW c2c routine and then normalizing.

I have installed the FFTW libraries on a 64-bit Linux system running centOS and am using the Intel 64 bit compiler (Version 12.0.0.084 Build 20101006). The FFTW libraries have been compiled using the Intel compiler.

Here is how I initialize the FFTW plan assuming a periodic domain of size (1:Nx,1:Ny,1:Nz):

```
INTEGER(8) :: plan_c2c_inv
COMPLEX(KIND(0.D0)),DIMENSION(:,:,:),ALLOCATABLE :: inv_in_c2c,inv_out_c2c
ALLOCATE( inv_in_c2c(Nx,Ny,Nz) )
ALLOCATE( inv_out_c2c(Nx,Ny,Nz) )
CALL dfftw_plan_dft_3d(plan_c2c_inv,Nx,Ny,Nz,inv_in_c2c,inv_out_c2c,FFTW_BACKWARD,FFTW_PATIENT)
```

I then go through a somewhat lengthy process to generate the Fourier space representation of the turbulent fluctuations over this portion of the 3-D complex arrays:

```
DO ii=1,Nx/2+1
    DO jj=1,Ny
        DO kk=1,Nz
            calculations to populate the complex array uhat(ii,jj,kk)
        ENDDO
    ENDDO
ENDDO
```

I then conjugate the complex array uhat by doing the calling a subroutine that performs the conjugation:

```
SUBROUTINE conjugate(uc)
    IMPLICIT NONE
    COMPLEX(KIND(0.D0)),DIMENSION(0:Nx-1,0:Ny-1,0:Nz-1),INTENT(INOUT) :: uc

    INTEGER :: i,j,k
    INTEGER :: ii,jj,kk

    uc(Nx/2,:,:) = (0.D0,0.D0)

    DO k=0,Nz-1,1
        DO j=0,Ny-1,1
            DO i=Nx/2+1,Nx-1,1
                ii = Nx - i
                jj = Ny - j
                kk = Nz - k
                IF (j.EQ.0) jj = 0
                IF (k.EQ.0) kk = 0
                uc(i,j,k) = CONJG(uc(ii,jj,kk))
            ENDDO
        ENDDO
    ENDDO
    DO k=0,Nz-1,1
        DO j=0,Ny-1,1
            i = 0
            ii = 0
            jj = Ny - j
            kk = Nz - k
            IF (j.EQ.0) jj = 0
            IF (k.EQ.0) kk = 0
            uc(i,j,k) = CONJG(uc(ii,jj,kk))
        ENDDO
    ENDDO

    RETURN
  END SUBROUTINE conjugate
```

My wavenumbers are defined as:

```
  DO ii=1,Nx/2+1
    k1(ii) = DBLE(ii-1)
  ENDDO
  DO ii=1,Nx/2-1
    k1(Nx/2+1+ii) = DBLE(-Nx/2+ii)
  ENDDO

  DO ii=1,Ny/2+1
    k2(ii) = DBLE(ii-1)
  ENDDO
  DO ii=1,Ny/2-1
    k2(Ny/2+1+ii) = DBLE(-Ny/2+ii)
  ENDDO

  DO ii=1,Nz/2+1
    k3(ii) = DBLE(ii-1)
  ENDDO
  DO ii=1,Nz/2-1
    k3(Nz/2+1+ii) = DBLE(-Nz/2+ii)
  ENDDO
```

When I convert uhat to real space I get a turbulent field that is clearly wrong and when I check the imaginary component of the converted 3-D array I get nonzero values, which indicates to me I may be missing something in my understanding of how to properly conjugate the complex Fourier space representation. Here is the code snippet that actually performs the conversion to real space:

```
SUBROUTINE FFTtoRealc2c(varhat_in,var_out)
  IMPLICIT NONE

  COMPLEX(KIND(0.D0)),DIMENSION(:,:,:),INTENT(IN) :: varhat_in
  REAL(KIND(0.D0)),DIMENSION(:,:,:),INTENT(INOUT) :: var_out

  inv_in_c2c = varhat_in
  CALL dfftw_execute_dft(plan_c2c_inv,inv_in_c2c,inv_out_c2c)
  var_out(1:Nx,1:Ny,1:Nz) = DBLE(inv_out_c2c)

  RETURN
END SUBROUTINE FFTtoRealc2c
```

When I spot check the conjugation it appears to be correct (at least by my understanding of it). For example, if I set Nx=Ny=Nz=16, then I see the conjugate of uhat(5,3,7) at uhat(13,15,11):

```
uhat(5,3,7) = (-5.137614165569777E-003,-4.527333137185095E-003)
uhat(13,15,11) = (-5.137614165569777E-003,4.527333137185095E-003)
```

The wavenumber magnitude also appears consistent at both points too:

```
sqrt(k1(5)*k1(5) + k2(3)*k2(3) + k3(7)*k3(7)) = 7.48331477354788
sqrt(k1(13)*k1(13) + k2(15)*k2(15) + k3(11)*k3(11)) = 7.48331477354788
```

So getting back to my question: do I have a correct understanding of how to define the complex conjugate of the Fourier space 3-D array?